# Should I use NuGet or not

Tags: .net, tfs, build, nuget

I am starting a Silverlight 4 / PRISM project (VS2010 SP1). I am looking at a good way to handle external libraries (like PRISM, EF, etc.) with TFS 2010.

Normally I would add a Libs folder, adding each external lib with its name and version below it, and add the dll's. Another option is to use NUGet, which is used in MVC3 kinda projects.

I also have a build server in mind, which I think should not be connected to the internet.

In this scenario, is it a good practice to use NUGet to load the assemblies locally in the workspace and then checkin in to TFS so that the libs will be shared among the other developers and the build server ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NuGet has nothing to do with MVC.
It is designed for use with all .Net projects.

By default (unless you enable Package Restore), NuGet packages (including DLLs) are checked into source control.
It should work fine with any build server.

Comment: I can't find an option to enable NUGet from a solution. How is it enabled when you create a new project ?

Comment: @PatrickPeters: NuGet does not need to be enabled.  Just right-click the `References` folder, then click Manage NuGet Packages.

Comment: I cannot find the 'Manage NuGet Packages'. I think the NuGet Package Manage should be installed first via the Extension Manager, isn't it ?

Comment: Correct.  SP1 includes NuGet; I had assumed you already installed it.

Comment: Had corrupted Visual Studio install